# Jedis DockerFile : Failed to connect to any host resolved for DNS name

Tags: java, docker, tcp, port, jedis

so I'm trying to dockerize my class , and when running the container I keep getting this Exception .

Here is my DockerFile :

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
WORKDIR app

#COPY target/streams-101-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar red.jar

COPY target/prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar","app.jar",<My IP address>,"6379"]
```

and I create my Jedis client like this :

```
host = args[0]
port = args[1]
HostAndPort config = new HostAndPort(host, port);
        PooledConnectionProvider provider = new PooledConnectionProvider(config);
        UnifiedJedis client = new UnifiedJedis(provider);
```

I tried to change ports and ip address from localhost to my actual machine Ip address and nothing works .

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your docker on the host network, i.e. use:

docker run --network host

To reach your local running Redis.